# Confusion with central charge in CFT and improvement of energy-momentum tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In theory of free scalar field
$$
S = \int d^2x \;\partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi
$$
$$
\langle \phi(z) \phi(w)\rangle \propto \ln(z-w)
$$

Exist [family of energy-momentum tensors](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9510145) (new term correspond to non-minimal coupling to gravity $\alpha R \phi^2$, [example with linear coupling $R\phi$](https://mcgreevy.physics.ucsd.edu/fall07/psets/soln03.pdf)):
$$
T_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi + \alpha (\partial_\mu\partial_\nu - \eta_{\mu\nu}\Box) \phi^2
$$
Obviously $\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu} = 0$, but $T_\mu^\mu \neq 0$ if $\alpha \neq 0$.
And 
$$
T = T_{zz}
=\partial_z \phi \partial_z \phi + \alpha (\partial_z\partial_z)\phi^2
=
(1+2\alpha)\partial_z \phi \partial_z \phi + 2\alpha \phi \partial_z^2\phi
$$

So this shift will affect standard OPE:
$$
T(z)T(w) = \frac{1/2}{(z-w)^4} + \frac{2T(w)}{(z-w)^2} + \frac{\partial T(w)}{(z-w)} + \dots
$$

To (I'm interested only in first term):
$$
T(z)T(w) = \frac{1/2 (1+6\alpha+10\alpha^2)}{(z-w)^4} + 
\frac{-1/2 \ln(z-w)}{(z-w)^4} + \frac{2T(w)}{(z-w)^2} (1+??) + \frac{\partial T(w)}{(z-w)}(1+??) + \dots
$$

And if one choose for example $\alpha = 1$, one obtain central charge $c = 17$ for free scalar field.. What about ln term in OPE?

Could someone to clarify and interpretate this confusion? Why we say that $c=1$ for free scalar filed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free scalar field can have any complex central charge, due to the linear modification of the energy-momentum tensor that you mention. The case $c=1$ is a bit special, in particular it allows compactification with an arbitrary radius, while for general $c$ the radius is quantized. See Section 4.1 of my review article for more details: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290

In the context of string theory, the free scalar with $c\neq 1$ is sometimes called the linear dilaton theory.

Comment: Thank you! Could you refer to concrete equations?

Comment: The tensor $T$ is given in (4.1.2). The extra term is linear. You use a quadratic extra term, which cannot be written in terms of the current $J=\partial \phi$ and its derivatives. Presumably this is why you get the $\ln$ term, which apparently breaks conformal symmetry, since your $TT$ OPE does not agree with the standard $TT$ OPE (2.2.10). Using the linear extra term, the central charge is given in terms of the coefficient $Q$ by (2.2.20).